# $\mathbb{R}$ - algebras in topological spaces

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebras

I´m reading an introduction to $\mathbb{R}$-algebras and in the text there is an observation that says:

If $X$ is a topological space, then the set of functions $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$ are a $\mathbb{R}$ - algebra and that the continuous functions are a subalgebra of the last space.

How can I prove this?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to show that $Hom(X,\mathbb{R})$ satisfies all the conditions to be an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra. The addition of two maps $f,g$ is given by $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ for all $x\in X$, multiplication is given by $(f.g)(x)=f(x).g(x)$, and scalar multiplication is given by $(r.f)(x)=r.(f(x))$. From this it's easy to see that the zero function is given by $0(x)=0$ for all $x\in X$ and the unit function is given by $1(x)=1$ for all $x\in X$.

Your job is to show that this is all well-defined and satisfies the necessary axioms of an associative $\mathbb{R}$-algebra.

Comment: but in the text said that  If I have R and A two ring with R confutative and A no necessarily A is a R-algebra if exist a morphism of ring from R to the center of A.

Comment: That makes precisely no sense... Could you write that again but being careful with your grammar and mathematical language?

Comment: R and A rings, R commutative A not necessarily commutative. A is called an R - algebra if there is a morphism ring R in the center of A

Comment: Given that $R$ here is a field ($\mathbb{R}$), an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ with a corresponding ring structure. The definition you're using is for arbitrary commutative rings and, while it generalises the notion of a $K$-algebra for field $K$, is more difficult to apply in this situation.

Comment: ok thanks i will prove your answer, thanks

Comment: @DanielRust: is the general definition really more difficult to apply?  The vector space axioms amount to exactly the same conditions as the fact that the corresponding map is a ring homomorphism.  And the ring $\mathrm{Hom}(X,\mathbb{R})$ is clearly commutative, so its centre is the whole of it, and so the homomorphism trivially lands in the centre.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine that's true, but I think the more abstract definition can mask the structure of the algebra. You also need to prove that $\mbox{Hom}(X,\mathbb{R})$ is a ring anyway which amounts to proving half the definition that it's an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra using the more concrete definition. In any case, it's worth knowing how to do it using both definitions.

Comment: Agreed, it’s worth knowing both definitions, and understanding the equivalence!  I wouldn’t say that the more general definition masks any structure, though — as you say, it comes down in the end to checking pretty much all the same things.  Indeed, I wouldn’t even say it’s more abstract — if anything, I think yours is closer to more abstract general versions like “an $R$-algebra is a monoid in the monoidal category $(R\text{-}\mathbf{Mod},\otimes)$”.

Comment: Excuse me one more question Are $\mathbb{z}$-algebras equal to the category of rings?